# Jquery add text to <label class='error'> dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to produce an error message that displays in `<label for='withold' class='error'></label>` but I can't figure out how to put the data into that label that has the class 'error'. I've tried the following:

```
if ($("label[for='withold']").hasClass( "error" ) ){
     $(this).text(data);
}
```

and

```
$("label[for='withold']").hasClass( ".error" ).text(data);
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Data is filled using .ajax success function:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "page.php",
    data: datastring,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "text",
    success:  function(data)
    {
        if (data.indexOf("Error") > -1) {
              $("label[for='withold']").hasClass( ".error" ).text(data);
        } else {}
       }
        });  // end $.ajax
```

Comment: the first one seems fine, the second wont work because `hasClass` simply returns a boolean. How are you filling data? Give more code/context

Comment: I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$("label.error[for='withold']").text(data);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/00fo9pq6/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `filter`

```
$("label[for='withold']").filter( ".error" ).text(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$("label[for='withold'].error").text(data);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vbbyyvpL/